# ANIMATEDTEXT eliminando todo o outros components da activity e como fazer para o mesmo ser executado em TextViews?

Tags: android, animate

Não consigo fazer com que essa animation rode nas minhas TextViews, além de que a mesma (animação) roda sem nenhum TextView nem nada do tipo na minha activity:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam, mesmo que eu adicione components à minha activity, eles somem na execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TypeWriter.class:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.animatedtext;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TypeWriter extends TextView {

    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mIndex;
    private long mDelay = 500;

    public TypeWriter(Context context){

        super(context);

    }

    public TypeWriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if (mIndex<=mText.length()){

                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

            }
        }
    };

    public void animateText(CharSequence text){

        mText=text;
        mIndex=0;

        setText("");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

    }

    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis){

        mDelay=millis;

    }

}
```

**Aparece um erro na seguinte linha => `public class TypeWriter extends TextView {`, porém nada que impeça a execução da aplicação.**

**MainActivity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.animatedtext;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TypeWriter writer = new TypeWriter(this);
        setContentView(writer);

        writer.setCharacterDelay(150);
        writer.animateText("(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!");

    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que os outros components não fossem excluídos e essa animação fosse executada em todos os TextViews que fossem adicionados a activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você usou o método `setContentView()` passando como parâmetro seu TextView animado. Você tem que passar somente o layout através do método, dessa forma: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` e em vez de instanciar o TextView animado do jeito que está fazendo, você deverá fazer assim:

```
Typewriter txtAnimado = (Typewriter) findViewById(R.id.meu_txt_animado);
```

No xml você deve digitar `<Typewriter` que o Android Studio completa o resto para você:

```js
<pacote.animatedtext.TypeWriter
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

**Uma maneira que eu julgo mais fácil de fazer isso, é adicionar o TextView normalmente e depois ir no seu xml e trocar `<TextView` por `<Typewriter`**, pois se você já tentar fazer com o TypeWriter só vai aparecer de começo `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` e `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` exatamente assim:

```js
<pacote.animatedtext.TypeWriter
        android:layout_width=""
        android:layout_height="" />
```

**Dessa forma você pode ter dificuldade em colocar o TextView na posição desejada, ainda mais se estiver utilizando o RelativeLayout.** Adicionando com TextView normal e depois trocando fica muito mais fácil, pois você só precisará trocar de TextView para TypeWriter, já tendo feito todo o seu posicionamento e referência em relação aos outros components.

Comment: corrigi o setContext, porém ocorreu um erro ao intanciar o textView. ele não aceitou o meu textView como typeWriter `TypeWriter writer = (TypeWriter)findViewById(R.id.tv);` acusou um erro.

Comment: Então no xml essa view cujo id é "tv" não é do tipo Typewriter...

Comment: só digite <Typewriter ...  que o Android studio vai auto-completar para você com os pacotes corretos de importação.